# Graham's Number versus another large number

Tags: inequality, big-numbers

I recently read this [article](http://www.soniccenter.org/sm/mtg/megacombo.html) about the most damage you can do in a single turn in Magic the Gathering. According to the current version of the deck, that damage is about

a) $2 \rightarrow 17 \rightarrow 417$

using [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation).

This got me thinking about whether this number is larger than Graham's Number (sorry, not allowed to put more than 2 links in a post). I've tried to work it out some, but I'm having trouble understanding the chained arrow notation, let alone comparing it to Graham's number.

If it helps, I noticed that Graham's number is between

b) $3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 64 \rightarrow 2$

and

c) $3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 65 \rightarrow 2$

But I don't know how that compares to

a) $2 \rightarrow 17 \rightarrow 417$

Thank you for your time, and any answers.

Edit: corrected typo in damage estimate "copied" from MTG site.

Comment: Well, you can any arbitrary amount of damage in a single turn in magic the gathering using infinite mana combos and fireball, for example.

Comment: The article you linked seems to end with the conclusion that the damage is $2 \rightarrow 17 \rightarrow 417$. Is the $4$ a typo, or something outside of the article?

Comment: @Sloan Good eye, that was a typo. Corrected it in original comment.

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons The problem stated on that site is that it is a finite amount of damage in the first turn (with perfect luck).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the article. Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, Grahams number should be much larger. Let $M=2 \rightarrow 17 \rightarrow 417$; in [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation) we have $M=2 \uparrow^{417} 17$. Let $G$ represent Graham's number. That is,
 $\left.
 \begin{matrix}
  G &=&3\underbrace{\uparrow \uparrow \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots \uparrow}3 \\
    & &3\underbrace{\uparrow \uparrow \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots \uparrow}3 \\
    & &\underbrace{\qquad\;\; \vdots \qquad\;\;} \\
    & &3\underbrace{\uparrow \uparrow \cdots\cdot\cdot \uparrow}3 \\
    & &3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow3
 \end{matrix}
\right \} \text{64 layers}$
This representation is both unwieldy and, I fear, not enlightening. Informally, we can think of $G$ as $3 \uparrow^{\text{massive}}3$. The heuristic argument in comparing two numbers in Knuth notation is that the one with more arrows is larger. This is not always the case (as explored [here](http://mrob.com/pub/math/largenum-3.html#hyper_po) and briefly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630537/algorithm-for-comparing-the-size-of-extremely-large-numbers)). For us, the number of arrows in $G$ ridiculously overwhelms the number of arrows in $M$ (the former I could never feasibly write out in decimal form and the latter is $3$-digits long). Hence, I think it's fair to say $M < G$.

Comment: I also had the same thought about the numbers, but I wasn't sure how the 17 affected it, compared to the 3. Though, I suppose the ridiculously larger number of up arrows in G overwhelms the 14 larger number after the arrows.

Comment: That's essentially what I've argued here! Very interesting article :)

Comment: Since $2 < 3$ and $17 < 3^3$, can we say that $3\uparrow^{2\times417}3$ is larger than M ?

Comment: I find it funny when we deal with numbers and we say something like $$3\uparrow^{massive}3$$Where we just say that spot has a very big number.

Comment: Already $G_2=3\uparrow^{3\uparrow \uparrow\uparrow \uparrow 3}\ 3$ is much larger than $2\uparrow^{417} 27$

Comment: Note, that $n\uparrow^n n<3\uparrow^{n+1} 3$ holds for $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 3):

In case you wonder about an actual proof: $$2 \uparrow^{417} 17 < 3 \uparrow^{417} 17 < 3 \uparrow^{417} 27 < 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 = 3 \uparrow^{418} 3 <  3 \uparrow^{3 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3} \; \; 3$$

The fact that Knuth's arrow notation is monotonous in all arguments is proven in
 [Saibian, Sbiis. A theorem for Knuth arrows.](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxsYXJnZW51bWJlcnN8Z3g6MzU3Y2U3NjVhMmEyZjY2YQ)

Comment: $ 3 \uparrow^{417} 27 < 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 = 3 \uparrow^{418} 3$ ?? Do you mean $ 3 \uparrow^{417} 27 < 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 \uparrow 3 = 3 \uparrow^{418} 3$ ?

Comment: @BusyAnt No, $3 \uparrow^{417} 3 \uparrow^{417} 3 = 3 \uparrow^{418} 3$. Please look to the definition again very carefully.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I misread the definition