# Could someone tell me how large this number is?

Tags: recursive-algorithms, big-numbers, hyperoperation

Context: If you guys didn't know, I'm running a nice little contest to see who can program the largest number.  More specific rules if you are interested may be found in [my chat room (click here to join)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art).  If you are entering, do note that I am accepting entries for quite a while (ignore all the deadlines :-)

---

Actually, maybe you are a little too late.

---

Now, before judging the size of any other numbers, I want to see how large [my number](https://repl.it/F7MS/32) is.  It uses [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation) and a nice little recursive function I made: (it's name is $\text{THING}_4(a,b,c,d,e)$)

$$f(a,b,c,d,e)=\begin{cases}z&;b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e<0\\f(z,b-1,c,d,e)&;b>0\\f(z,z,c-1,d,e)&;c>0\\f(z,z,z,d-1,e)&;d>0\\f(z,z,z,z,e-1)&;e\ge0\end{cases}$$

Where $z=a\uparrow^{a+3}(a+1)$.  This must also be evaluated top to bottom.  For example, you must check if $b>0$ before checking if $c>0$.

An example of how this function goes:

$$f(2,2,2,2,2)=f(2\uparrow^53,1,2,2,2)=f((2\uparrow^53)\uparrow^{(2\uparrow^53)+3}((2\uparrow^53)+1),0,2,2,2)\\x=(2\uparrow^53)\uparrow^{(2\uparrow^53)+3}((2\uparrow^53)+1)\\=f(x,x,1,2,2)\\=f(x\uparrow^{x+3}(x+1),x-1,1,2,2)$$

Clearly, if you keep the expansion up, it is clear this is much larger than Graham's number.  Particularly, $f(2,2,1,0,0)>G$.

---

My particular number is $f(9,9,9,9,f(9,9,9,9,9))$, and it's name is $SBA_4$, as per the initials of my username.

> Does anyone know how to describe this number in terms of [FGH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) or [similar notation](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_googological_functions) that sizes up how large a number is?  Ultimately, I want to see where my number stands on the [list of googolisms](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_googologisms), but I cannot tell.

---

Updates:

---

### $2/11/17:$

[BEAF](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Bowers_Exploding_Array_Function) looks like a good candidate to compare to my function.  Looking into it...

Comparing to BEAF and similar things, I think my number lies somewhere at the [chained arrow notation level](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_googologisms/Chained_arrow_notation_level).  I am thinking it lies around maybe $\{a,b,3,2\}$ or higher.

---

### $2/12/17:$

Actually, I think that my number is larger than [Megaior megocal](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Megaior_megocal).  Particularly,

$$SBA_4>>f(9,9,9,9,0)\stackrel?>\operatorname{forcal}_3(2)$$

which puts my number somewhere around $\{a,b,4+,2\}$.

In general, I think [Aarex's Graham generator](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Aarex%27s_Graham_Generator) is a nice comparison (at least in my head, I can compare the two somewhat easily).

I'm also trying to see if I can compare $SBA_4$ to [Hypercal](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hypercal).  I'm fairly certain that $SBA_4>\text{Hypercal}$, but its a little bit fuzzy in my mind.

---

### $2/13/17$

I think I've finally found some good bounds:

$$\text{Hypercal}<SBA_4<\text{Hyperior Hyperior Hyperior Hypercal}$$

[Hyperior Hyperior Hyperior Hypercal](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/hyperior_hyperior_hyperior_hypercal).

---

### $7/27/2017:$

Not sure why you're still here, but if you just want to see what I've come up just for the heck of it, I've made [this program](https://repl.it/Jfcr/12):

```
def f(a,b=[a,a],c=[a,a])d,*e=b;g,h=c;a.times{a+=(b.class==Fixnum)?a:b.size<2?f(a,d,c):d<0?f(a,e,[g+1,h]):g>0?f(a,[a,d-1,e],[g-1,h]):h<0?f(a,[d-1,e],c):f(a,b,[a,h-1])};a end
```

When run, $f(n)$ outputs numbers roughly on the scale of $f_{\omega^{\omega^2}+\omega^\omega}(n)$ in the fast growing hierarchy.

In English, the expansions rules basically work as follows:

$$f(n)=f(n,[n,n],[n,n])$$

$b=[b_1,b_2,\dots,b_i]$, $d=b_1$ and $e=[b_2,\dots,b_i]$.  Let $n$ be an integer.

$$f(a,n,c)=2^aa$$

---

$$f(a,[b],c)=u_a\\u_0=a,u_{n+1}=u_n+f(u_n,b,c)$$

---

$$b_1<0\implies f(a,b,[g,h])=v_a\\v_0=a,v_{n+1}=v_n+f(v_n,e,[g+1,h])$$

---

$$b_1\ge0\land g>0\implies f(a,b,[g,h])=w_a\\w_0=a,w_{n+1}=w_n+f(w_n,[a,d-1,e],[g-1,h])$$

Note that if $b=[1,2,3]$, then $[a,d-1,e]=[a,0,[2,3]]\ne[a,0,2,3]$.

---

$$b_1\ge0\land g\le0\land h\ge0\implies f(a,b,[g,h])=x_a\\x_0=a,x_{n+1}=x_n+f(x_n,b,[a,h-1])$$

---

$$b_1\ge0\land g\le0\land h<0\implies f(a,b,[g,h])=x_a\\x_0=a,x_{n+1}=x_n+f(x_n,[d-1,e],[g,h])$$

---

To see examples, tr [here](https://repl.it/Jfcr/13).  To see it worked out, I'll take the time to type out the expansion of $f(2)$ below:

$f(2)=f(2,[2,2],[2,2])\\=2+\underbrace{f(2,[2,1,[2]],[1,2])}+f(2+f(2,[2,1,[2]],[1,2]),[2,1,[2]],[1,2])\\\implies f(2,[2,1,[2]],[1,2])=2+\underbrace{f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[0,2])}+f(2+f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[0,2]),[2,1,[1,[2]]],[0,2])\\\implies f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[0,2])=2+\underbrace{f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[2,1])}+f(2+f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[2,1]),[2,1,[1,[2]]],[2,1])\\\implies f(2,[2,1,[1,[2]]],[2,1])=2+f(2,[2,1,[1,[1,[2]]]],[1,1])+f(2+f(2,[2,1,[1,[1,[2]]]],[1,1]),[2,1,[1,[1,[2]]]],[1,1])\\\vdots$

So as you can see, the amount of recursion gets kinda crazy, and the amount of arrays will slowly explode.

Comment: Interesting question. Would also be interesting to see how it stacks up to a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number.

Comment: @Moo I assure you, $f(2,2,2,2,2)>G$.

Comment: You'll never beat Rayo's number.

Comment: @Wolfram Well I don't plan to.  It's just a nice recreational contest for fun.

Comment: What are $f$ anf $g$ in the first conditional branch? How is $f(a,0,0,0,0)$ defined?defined

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh whoops, :D

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Also, the notation in the given link is different, but its basically the same thing as I have here.

Comment: @Moo Let me correct myself.  I'm fairly certain $f(2,2,1,0,0)>G$.

Comment: Is this number for a real application?

Comment: @Moo The application is the first 3 lines :D

Comment: The problem in these "large number" contests is not defining a number but comparing two quite differently defined numbers.

Comment: @martycohen all the more fun, all the more painful.

Comment: I apologize for all the edits.  Since I doubt the edits would affect any answers in progress, and since this is for a contest, I thought I would update my post to the newer number, so long as there are no dramatic changes.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My bad.  Did not catch the typos quite easily.  Fixed it.

Comment: Of course the way to win a large number contest is to use the number "one plus the maximum of all other entries". Well, unless someone else uses the same definition, then you've got a problem ;-)

Comment: @celtschk Lol, but I do not think someone will be so sly as to such.  Also, the restriction of "no importing other functions or numbers" negates such things.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Yes, I've now checked out your contest, and one of the rules is a limitation of size; that means you cannot simply add the code of all other contestants (or even just the best one) to your own code and add some "+1" somewhere, unless the other person wasted an obvious opportunity to make the own number bigger. Or in short, a good entry necessarily will use up almost all of the available characters.

Comment: @martycohen As I have learned, it's not terribly bad with the fast growing hierarchy.  FGH is pretty good, unless the numbers are too close I do think.

Comment: @Moo If only you knew the things I've done in all this time... I've even created notations like PAIN (powerful array iteration notation), the bump function, and the bump ordinal collapsing function.  They are real scary...

Comment: @martycohen There once was such a "large number" contest called the [Bignum Bake Off](http://djm.cc/bignum-results.txt), and while it was true many thought it'd be quite difficult comparing the numbers, it turned out that it wasn't so hard (as explained in the link).  For the most part, one could probably through away unnecessary parts of the program and replace them with upper bounds that fit into the fast growing hierarchy to get good comparisons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function lies at $f_{\omega+4}$ in the fast-growing hierarchy; that is, your $f(n,n,n,n,n)$ is roughly $f_{\omega+4}(n)$.

First, let us set $g(n) = n \uparrow^{n+3} (n+1)$.  Note that

$$2 \uparrow^{n-1}(n+1) < f_\omega (n) < 2 \uparrow^{n-1}(2n)$$

so for $n \ge 2$,

$$f_{\omega}(n) = f_n(n) < 2 \uparrow^{n-1}(2n) < g(n) < 2 \uparrow^{n+3}(n+5) < f_\omega(n+4)$$

Now we have $$f(a,0,0,0,0) = f(g(a),g(a),g(a),g(a),-1) = g(g(a))$$

Further, $$f(a,1,0,0,0) = f(g(a),0,0,0,0) = g(g(g(a))) = g^3(a)$$

and by induction we have $$f(a,b,0,0,0) = g^{b+2}(a)$$

In particular we have $f(a,a,0,0,0) = g^{a+2}(a)$, and

$$f_{\omega+1}(a) = f_{\omega}^a(a) < g^a(a) < g^{a+2}(a)$$

The other direction is a little tricker; however we can use the fact that $$f_{\omega}(a+1) > f_{\omega}(a) + 5$$ when $a \ge 2$, so setting $u(a) = f_{\omega}(a)$ and $v(a) = f_{\omega}(a+4)$, we have

$$u^n(a+5) = u^{n-1}(u(a+5)) = u^{n-1}(v(a+1)) > u^{n-1}(v(a)+5) = u^{n-2}(u(v(a)+5)) = u^{n-2}(v(v(a)+1)) > u^{n-2}(v(v(a)+5)) = \ldots > v^n(a)+5$$

Thus $$f_{\omega+1}(a+3) = u^{a+3}(a+3) = u^{a+2}(u(a+3)) > u^{a+2}(a+5) > v^{a+2}(a) > g^{a+2}(a)$$

and we have proven
 $$f_{\omega+1}(a) < f(a,a,0,0,0) < f_{\omega+1}(a+3)$$

The rest of the letters follow a similar pattern. Define $h(a) = g^a(a)$.  Then we have

$$f(a,a,1,0,0) = f(g^a(a), 0, 1,0,0) = f(h(a),0,1,0,0) = f(g(h(a)),g(h(a)),0,0,0) = f(h(g(h(a))),0,0,0,0) = g(g(h(g(h(a)))))$$

$$f(a,a,2,0,0) = f(h(a),0,2,0,0) = f(g(h(a)),g(h(a)),1,0,0) = g(g(h(g(h(g(h(a))))))) = g(gh)^3(a)$$

and by induction again,

$$f(a,a,c,0,0) = g(gh)^{c+1}(a)$$

Now both $gh(a) = g^{a+1}(a)$ and $ggh(a) = g^{a+2}(a)$ lie between $f_{\omega+1}(a)$ and $f_{\omega+1}(a+3)$, so $f(a,a,c,0,0) =g(gh)^{c+1}(a)$ is greater than $f_{\omega+1}^{c+1}(a)$, and by the same argument as the $u,v$ argument above we can show that $f(a,a,c,0,0)$ is less than $f_{\omega+1}^{c+1}(a+4)$.

So
$$f_{\omega+2}(a) = f_{\omega+1}^a(a) < f_{\omega+1}^{a+1}(a) < f(a,a,a,0,0) < f_{\omega+1}^{a+1}(a+4) < f_{\omega+1}^{a+1}(f_{\omega+1}(a+2)) = f_{\omega+1}^{a+2}(a+2) = f_{\omega+2}(a+2)$$

Using the same reasoning, we can show that $$f_{\omega+3}(a) < f(a,a,a,a,0) < f_{\omega+3}(a+2)$$ and $$f_{\omega+4}(a) < f(a,a,a,a,a) < f_{\omega+4}(a+2)$$

In terms of Conway chained arrow notation, $f(a,a,a,a,a)$ will be approximately $a \rightarrow a \rightarrow a+1 \rightarrow 5$.

In terms of BEAF, $f(a,a,a,a,a)$ will be approximately $\lbrace a,a+1,4,2 \rbrace$.

Comment: Wow, wonderful timing.  I just finally figured out FGH on my own, so I quickly realized this.  By the way, for the BEAF at the end there, you can use `\{a,a+1,4,2\}`.  Thank you so much for the lengthy answer!

Answer (score 2):

In [BEAF](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Bowers_Exploding_Array_Function) notation, I have deduced that

$$f(a,0,0,0,0)\approx\{a,2,1,2\}$$

$$f(a,b,0,0,0)\approx\{a,b+1,2,2\}$$

$$f(a,b,1,0,0)\approx\underbrace{\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{}_{\{a,b+1,2,2\}}\dots\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}$$

$$f(a,b,c,0,0)\approx(c+1)\left\lbrace\tiny\underbrace{\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{}_{\underbrace{\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{}_{\underbrace{\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{a,\{}_{\underbrace{\vdots}_{\{a,b+1,2,2\}}}\dots\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}}\dots\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}}\dots\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}+1,2,2\}\right.$$

Unless someone can simplify this, BEAF isn't going to be enough, but it looks like a good start.

---

Maybe BEAF is a good place, but I'm going to have to understand more about it's nature for more terms in the array and larger numbers at the end.

:-(